Is it possible to change the display name of an Azure communication service MailFrom address?
I have recently created an Azure email communication service, to send automatic emails from a web app I am developing. I created a new MailFrom address (DoNotReply@mydomain.com) with the display name DoNotReply. I want to edit it and change the display name to something more user-friendly. For example, the name of my app, so the users know immediately where the email is coming from. Is it possible to change the display name of the existing MailFrom address, and if yes how, or should I delete it and create a new MailFrom address with the desired display name.

Go to Provision Domains in Email Communication Service, click on the domain=>Mail From Address=>Add(add the preferred display name and mail from address). Check this article.

Thank you very much for your comment! So I can't edit the already existing MailFrom address and I have to create a new one?

Check my answer below to achieve your requirement.

As mentioned in the comments, it is possible to change the display name of an Azure communication service Mail From address, refer MSDOC.

Open your Email Communication Service.
Navigate to the Settings=> Provision Domains, select your Domain.



Navigate to Mail From Address under Email Services.



Select Add and enter the preferred Display Name and MailFrom address. Click Save.
This allows to create multiple Send Addresses with preferred Display names.

You can use the PowerShell commands to update the display name to your Sender Username of the domain, refer MSDOC:
1. az communication email domain sender-username update --email-service-name "<EmailServiceName>" --resource-group "<resourceGroup>" --domain-name "<domain_name>" --sender-username "<username>" --display-name "<displayname>"

2. az communication email domain sender-username update --email-service-name "<EmailServiceName>" --resource-group "<resourceGroup>" --domain-name "<domain_name>" --sender-username "<username>" --display-name "<displayname>" --subscription "<subscriptionId>"


I could update the display name of my domain donotreply@domain.com as shown below:

PS /home/uname> az communication email domain sender-username update --email-service-name "pravallikaecs" --resource-group "rgname" --domain-name "AzureManagedDomain" --sender-username "donotreply" --display-name "Contoso News Alerts" --subscription "b83c1ed3-cxxxx-2b83a074c23f"

{
  "displayName": "Contoso News Alerts",
  "id": "/subscriptions/b83cxxxxx074c23f/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Communication/emailServices/pravallikaecs/domains/AzureManagedDomain/senderUsernames/donotreply",
  "name": "donotreply",
  "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
  "resourceGroup": "rgname",
  "systemData": {
    "createdAt": "2024-06-26T11:00:17.4708833Z",
    "createdBy": "vxxx@xxx.com",
    "createdByType": "User",
    "lastModifiedAt": "2024-06-26T11:00:17.4708833Z",
    "lastModifiedBy": "vxxxx@xxxx.com",
    "lastModifiedByType": "User"
  },
  "type": "microsoft.communication/emailservices/domains/senderusernames",
  "username": "donotreply"
}


